# Jenkins - Build Status

Tags: ant, jenkins, continuous-integration

I've created one Jenkins job to execution 5 test cases and it works, but not in terms of build creation.

> Build status is coming as SUCCESS even if there is any failure test
>   cases during execution.

For instance, 2 test cases out of 5 got failed during my recent run, but the build status has become SUCCESS!!!

Please help me in correcting this.....

***Note:*** I'm using `Jenkins 1.617` & `ANT 1.9.4` for the integration.

Comment: You should return 1 to mark a Jenkins job fail. Can you give some fail log?

Comment: Where should I make the configuration to return 1? Can you please give me some reference?

Comment: Are you using Robot Framework to launch your test cases?

Comment: Well not Robot, I'm using our organization's internal framework which is Hybrid type. Do we need to install any plug-ins for managing build status or we have any other option to do that in general.....

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing junits in jenkins, default status is unstable for jenkins job and success for maven/ant build.

If you are using an ant build add the below property to junit task to make the build failed **failureproperty="test.failed"**. If you want to fail the build even if one junit fails, add property **haltonfailure="yes"**

If you are using maven add the argument **-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false**